# Array containing only 0 and 1 values

Tags: c#, arrays, data-structures

I need an array which will only contain the values 0 and 1. Will `bool[]` be good enough for me? Or is there something lighter weight?

**EDIT:**

I dont have memory constraints but that array is made and passes online All The Time with big files passes concurrently with that array. I want the maximun optimization so the big files wont be delayed

Comment: [`System.Collections.BitArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx).

Comment: `weigh too much`? What are you memory constraints?

Comment: I dont have memory constraints but that array is made and passes online All The Time.

Comment: Well, if you don't state your constraints, we are not likely to give you an answer suitable to your needs.

Comment: Not sure I agree with downvotes on this. Seems a fair question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bool is probably not the best way to do it. Depends how many numbers you have got.

It is important to realise that even though a bool is a single bit, it requires a full byte in memory.

A BitArray on the other hand takes care of this for you and is more space efficient, although ever so slightly less time efficient.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx

Depends on your constraints, if it is not for a constrained environment a bool array will work just fine.

Comment: I dont have memory constraints but that array is made and passes online All The Time with big files passes concurrently with that array. I want the maximun optimization so the big files wont be delayed. So what do you sujjest now?

Comment: @StavAlfi Define "big", how big?

Comment: And what do you need to do with it? I'm struggling to see why it needs to be stored as an array at all?

Comment: I promiss you that it wont help you if I will explain my application. I will go with your idea. Thank you.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/16416/discussion-between-stav-alfi-and-kingcronus)

Answer (score 1):

Bool Array is good enough. You can consider "false" as `0` and "true" as `1`.

Comment: Not necesserily. A Bool costs 8bits of memory, wasteful for something which can be held in a single bit.

Comment: @KingCronus I'm not that sure about it, but as I know the minimum bits that a CPU can handle are 8 bits, that's why it doesn't matter.

Comment: I know that. If you have to store 8 bools, you propose using 8 bytes. I propose using 1 byte, like 01010101 - The OP can then use one eighth of the memory. Of course, retrieving a particular value is slightly more complex, but of course possible.

Answer (score 1):

May be you need  [BitArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.collections.bitarray.aspx), the sequence of `1` and `0`.

Comment: what are the deffrences between bool[] and BitArray?

Comment: @StavAlfi: BitArray uses one **bit** for each value,  bool[], instead, uses one **byte** for each value.

Answer (score 0):

`bool[]` would do the trick... If your 0 & 1 numbers are in fact just "Flags" and not real numbers.

Using an `Enum` with the `Flags` attribute is another option. This would allow you to have an `Intention Revealing Name` for both boolean values.

```
[Flags()]
public enum TheFlags
{
    NoneSet = 0,
    FirstSet = 1,
    SecondSet = 2
}
```

Then you can check if "First" is set like so:

```
TheFlags flags = TheFlags.FirstSet;
if (flags.HasFlag(TheFlags.FirstSet))
    Console.WriteLine("First flag is set!");
```